# LibGDX - Couldn't load dependencies of FreetypeFont asset

Tags: java, libgdx, asset-management

Hi I'm currently stuck on trying to load a `.ttf` font, I'm getting a GdxRuntimeException with the message: `Couldn't load dependencies of asset: coastershadowfont`

```
FileHandleResolver resolver = new InternalFileHandleResolver();

assetManager.setLoader(FreeTypeFontGenerator.class, new FreeTypeFontGeneratorLoader(resolver));

assetManager.setLoader(BitmapFont.class, ".ttf", new FreetypeFontLoader(resolver));

FreetypeFontLoader.FreeTypeFontLoaderParameter params = new FreetypeFontLoader.FreeTypeFontLoaderParameter();

params.fontFileName = "fonts/coastershadow.ttf";
params.fontParameters.size = 30;

assetManager.load("coastershadowfont", BitmapFont.class, params);

try {
    assetManager.finishLoadingAssets();
} catch (Exception exception) {
    System.out.println(exception.toString());
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Pass fileName with extension, when you call `load(...)` method on `AssetManager`. FileName should be anything with extension.

```
assetManager.load("coastershadowfont.ttf", BitmapFont.class, params); //Adds the given asset to the loading queue of the AssetManager.
assetManager.finishLoading();  // triggered to execute task
```

And get `BitmapFont` with fileName that you specified at loading time.

```
font= assetManager.get("coastershadowfont.ttf",BitmapFont.class);
```

Comment: It's working now, it seems that really was the problem. ty